# Php - Check if variable value exists in file

Tags: php

I am working on a script that saves a list of urls to a file each time it runs.

Each time the script runs, it should check the file and if the url is not already included in the file, it should post that url to facebook. If the url is already in the file, it should not post it to facebook.

Right now, each time the script runs, one url is getting posted to facebook even though it's already in the file. Not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
<?php

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/');
require_once(__DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

require('simple_html_dom.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxx',
 'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);



$html = file_get_html('https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/McKinney,TX/300000p_price/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/date;d_sort/');

$houses = [];

$i = 1;

foreach ($html->find('.cardContainer') as $house) {
    if ($i > 2) {
        break;
    }

    $houseLink = $house->find('a.tileLink', 0);

    $houseUrl = 'https://trulia.com' . $houseLink->href;

    file_put_contents("houses.txt", ($houseUrl . "\n"), FILE_APPEND);

    $singleHouseHtml = file_get_html("{$houseUrl}");

    $singleHouseHtmlDesc = $singleHouseHtml->find('span#corepropertydescription', 0);

    $singleHouseHtmlDescText = $singleHouseHtmlDesc->plaintext;

    $houseFile = file_get_contents("houses.txt");

    if(strpos($houseFile, $houseUrl) == false) {
        $linkData = [
            'link' => $houseUrl,
            'message' => $singleHouseHtmlDescText
        ];
        $pageAccessToken ='xxxxxxxxx';

        try {
            $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    } 


    $houses[] = [
        'url' => $houseUrl,
        'desc' => $singleHouseHtmlDesc
    ];

    $i++;

}


var_dump($houses);
```

Comment: This may not be the right answer but this is what I would do instead of  appending the new url into the file with a new line... use csv this would make reading a easier job also for every .cardContainer you are performing I/O why not do it once at the top of the script load all of your houses into memory convert the csv into an array and then check the array to see if  url exist if it doesn't then assign that to an array if it does then don't and at the end of the script add the new array to the csv.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` function cant check all lines ( as you uses \n ). So replace it with preg_match ( with `s` flag ) and you are done:

```
if (!preg_match("~$houseUrl~s", $houseFile)) {
```

Your Optimized Code:

```
<?php

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/');
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'app_secret'            => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$html = file_get_html('https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/McKinney,TX/300000p_price/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/date;d_sort/');

$houses = [];

$house = $html->find('.cardContainer', 0);

$houseLink = $house->find('a.tileLink', 0);

$houseUrl = 'https://trulia.com' . $houseLink->href;

file_put_contents("houses.txt", ($houseUrl . "\n"), FILE_APPEND);

$singleHouseHtml = file_get_html($houseUrl);

$singleHouseHtmlDesc = $singleHouseHtml->find('span#corepropertydescription', 0);

$singleHouseHtmlDescText = $singleHouseHtmlDesc->plaintext;

$houseFile = file_get_contents("houses.txt");

if (!preg_match("~$houseUrl~s", $houseFile)) {
    $linkData = [
        'link'    => $houseUrl,
        'message' => $singleHouseHtmlDescText,
    ];
    $pageAccessToken = 'xxxxxxxxx';

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
}

$houses[] = [
    'url'  => $houseUrl,
    'desc' => $singleHouseHtmlDesc,
];

var_dump($houses);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this actually isn't working either. When I go this route, no urls are being posted.

Comment: Only the condition